# Two numbers addition in java

Tags: java, linked-list

You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order, and each of their nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum as a linked list.

You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

I have tried the following solution but error is Time Limit Exceeded.

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {      
       ListNode a = l1;
       ListNode b = l2;
       ListNode head = new ListNode(0); 
       ListNode temp = head; 
       int carry = 0;
       while (a != null || b != null)
       {
         int x = (a!= null) ? a.val : 0;
         int y = (b!= null) ? b.val : 0;
         int sum = carry + x + y;
         carry = sum /10;
         ListNode news = new ListNode(sum%10); 
         temp.next = news; 
         temp = temp.next;  
         if (a.next != null) a = a.next;  
         if (b.next != null) b = b.next; 
       }
         if (carry > 0) {
         temp.next = new ListNode(carry);
    }
       return head.next; 
    }
}
```

Comment: "error is Time Limit Exceeded."? Where do you get that message? This is not a message that the normal Java runtime provides, is this some exercise site?

Comment: You only re-set `a` (and `b` similarly) if `a.next` is not `null`. That means you'll always infinitely loop, as your end-condition is never reached. You'll keep looking at  the last digit in perpetuitiy.

Comment: You only set `a = a.next` in the case of `if (a.next != null)`, so you made sure with your if clause that `a` never becomes `null`. The same for `b`. Yet `a` or `b` becoming null is your  loops stopping condition. So to me it looks like you made an endless loop that never reaches its stopping condition.

Comment: In future: run your solution locally rather than relying on the exercise site for initial feedback. That will allow you to see whether your program terminates, and to use your debugger to see what's happening if it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modify these two lines:

```
if (a.next != null) a = a.next;  
if (b.next != null) b = b.next;
```

to

```
if (a != null) a = a.next;  
if (b != null) b = b.next;
```